# How to add jquery and javascript to the same file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if this is possible. This is how my js file will look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li#dropdown").on('click', function(e) {
       $('#toggleList').slideToggle();
       e.preventDefault();
    });  
});

//javascript code...
```

Will this be possible? or is it better to have my javascript code in another file

Comment: jQuery is a library written *in* JavaScript. You can use them both in the same file, because it's both the same scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends entirely on what you want to do.

If your javascript has code, that will be used inside of your $().ready event then you should put it before the $().ready.

The rule is code with functions to do specific stuff, you can call it "your" library, and you should put that code in a separated file.

Code that deals with event handling of your page controls, you should put on a file with [the name of the page].js, but this is just a way for you to organize stuff.

Because javascript is so flexible if you want you can put all in the same file, and it will work generally.

Comment: jquery will handle all button events, while my javascript will handle a geocoding that I will do for a store locator

Comment: ok, well then, put your geo code function inside a GeoCodingLib.js, and the code to work with page specific events in a file called MyGeoPage.js. You could put all into the same messy-code.js, but separate both concerns is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is an library made out of javascript code.

So actually you are writing javascript in javascript.

So you can combine it, what is already combined :P

haha

You can script inside jquery with javascript goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

That is going to work well and accurate. There is no issue with the code, to be written in jQuery or JavaScript.

jQuery is just a library written in JavaScript. jQuery just shorten downs the code for you. There is no other major difference.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li#dropdown").on('click', function(e) {
       $('#toggleList').slideToggle();
       e.preventDefault();
    });  
});
```

Would work in every browser, when you have included your jQuery plugin in your web app. Otherwise browser won't be able to recognize `$` character and you'll get error. That's the thing you need to worry about only.

`.slideToggle()` is just a method; function, or jQuery. `e` is handler for event, and the preventDefault is also a part of JavaScript. So you can see, that jQuery and JavaScript are alike. There is no major difference.

JavaScript is executed by every browser. So it would be executed as it is by every browser.